# Book about a kid living on a planet where they are researching alien creatures

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

The book is about a kid living in a base on a planet where they are researching alien creatures.

It was a juvenile sci-fi book. I think it was part of a shared universe; a few authors wrote in.

I thought the title of the book was *Starfish Station*, but I can not find anything with that name, so I could be wrong.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, can you tell us anything more about the plot or characters? For example, what were the alien creatures like? Were they advanced or primitive? Peaceful or aggressive? Land-based or marine-based? Etc.

Answer (score 6):

Is this ***[Starswarm](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/197277.Starswarm)*** (1998) by Jerry Pournelle...?

It's the fifth book in the *[Jupiter](https://www.goodreads.com/series/56944-jupiter)* series. The first four books in the series were authored by Charles Sheffield, while the sixth and currently final book was authored by James P. Hogan.

> Kit has never known any life but his existence at the protected laboratory compound known as Starswarm Station. And for all that time he has heard the an artificial intelligence chip implanted in his skull. It guides him and helps protect him from the planet's many dangers, including roaming bands of hostile centaurs and "haters." But the startling discovery of who put the chip in his head - and why - leads Kip to revelations that could threaten the safety of the entire compound.
>
> [image: Front cover of "Starswarm" by Jerry Pournelle.]

From a [review](https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/41475/):

> **Kip, an orphan, lives with his uncle and a small community of scientists and their families at Starswarm Station on Paradise, a planet that has been colonized from Earth under corporate sponsorship. Starswarm Station is named after one of the life forms the scientists are studying; a specimen lives in a lake near the settlement.** This life form was named a starswarm because of its ability to produce twinkling, starlike lights. Life at the station is relatively peaceful until the planet's governing corporation starts paying entirely too much attention to Starswarm and its inhabitants. There are multiple reasons for this interest, and these reasons supply the action and the conflict that made this novel a compelling and compulsive read for me.

Comment: Thank you so much this is the book

Comment: @gary mccullough - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.